# Can we extract dyanmic data from string using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to validate and get the data for following tags(9F03,9F02,9C ) using regex:
9F02060000000060009F03070000000010009C0101

Above string is in Tag - length - value format.

Where 9F02,9F03,9C are tags and have fixed length but their position and value in string can vary.

Just after the tag there is the length of the value in bytes that tag can store.

for example:

9F02=tag

06=Length in bytes

000000006000= value

Thanks,

Ashutosh

Comment: What have you tried until now? Why do you need to use regex? the size is dynamic or fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegEx {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "9F02060000000060009F03070000000010009C0101";

    String regEx = "(9F02|9F03|9C)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Tag : "+ m.group());
        String length = s.substring(m.end(), m.end()+2);
        System.out.println("Length : " + length);
        int valueEndIndex = new Integer(m.end()) + 3 + new Integer(length);
        String value = s.substring(m.end()+3,valueEndIndex);
        System.out.println("Value : "+ value);
    }
}
```

}

This code will give you following output :

```
Tag : 9F02
Length : 06
value : 000000
Tag : 9F03
Length : 07
value : 0000000
Tag : 9C
Length : 01
value : 1
```

I am not sure about byte length you are mentioning here, but I guess this code shall help you kick start!

Comment: I was able to do it using substring method in C# but I wanted to know how we can do it from regex.
I have to study regex methods of .Net to use them more efficiently.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Standard regex doesn't know how to count very well, it behaves like a state machine in that way.

What you can do though if the number of possibilities is small is represent each possibility in a state in regex, and use multiple regex queries for each tag ...

```
/9F02(01..|02....|03......)/
/9C(01..|02....)/
```

... And so on.

Example here.

http://rubular.com/r/euHRxeTLqH